# Android HttpURLConnection write post data

Tags: java, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to send post data through HttpURLConnection and it doesn't seem to send the post data.

I'm able to output the data through Toast immediately before trying to send a POST request, but when I check on the server side it makes the connects to the PHP file, but the POST data is empty.

So, I know the data exists in the jsonObject.
    I also know it makes it to the try catch statement, but when I connect it's not being sent or received properly.

```
try {
        URL url = new URL(emailURL);
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/json");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString( jsonObject.toString().length() ));
        conn.setUseCaches( false );

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());

        wr.write(jsonObject.toString());

          wr.close();

        BufferedReader reader = null;
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

        // Read Server Response
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            // Append server response in string
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        String text = "";
        text = sb.toString();



    } catch (Exception e) {

        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
```

Comment: just a question, you know there are libraries that make your job much easier and you don't use them or not?

Comment: Are there really?  I'm new to Android development so this is all new to me.

Comment: try this: http://loopj.com/android-async-http/ instagram uses that, and lots of famous apps, saves lots of pain.

Comment: `text = sb.toString();`. What do you get back as text?

Comment: OkHttp or Volley are two other libraries that make POST really easy

Comment: Come on guys. He only needs one more line of code, not a whole new API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to adding method to make sure it really connect to your server.

modify your code like :

```
    int responseCodeFromServer = -1;
    try {
         responseCodeFromServer=conn.getResponseCode();
    } catch (Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if (responseCodeFromServer == HttpsURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
         BufferedReader reader = null;
         reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
         StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;

       // Read Server Response
       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          // Append server response in string
          sb.append(line + "\n");
       }

       String text = "";
       text = sb.toString();
    }
```

So if there's something wrong while connecting to your servers  you will see an exception.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by 'adding method'?

Comment: i mean adding condition to detect respose code from server, see variable responseCodeFromServer.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing happens until you get the response code or the input or error stream. You must do one of these things.

NB You don't need to set the content-length. Java does that for you. Similarly, `setDoOutput(true)` sets the request method to POST.

Comment: I thought `setRequestMethod( "POST" );` set the request method :)

Comment: @cricket_007 Of course it does, but the OP is already calling `setDoOutput()`, which also does. See the Javadoc.

Answer (score -1):

```
conn.setRequestProperty( "charset", "utf-8");
conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Length", Integer.toString(jsonObject.toString().length() ));
conn.setUseCaches( false );

conn.connect(); // this is missing in your code

OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
```

Comment: `connect()` is automatic. See the Javadoc. It is not missing.

Comment: JavaDoc says "URLConnection objects go through two phases: first they are created, then they are connected. After being created, and before being connected, various options can be specified (e.g., doInput and UseCaches). After connecting, it is an error to try to set them. Operations that depend on being connected, like getContentLength, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary."

Comment: @EJP "connect() is NOT automatic". https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29

Comment: Rubbish. Read your own citation: ["Operations that depend on being connected, like getContentLength, will implicitly perform the connection, if necessary."](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html#connect%28%29) You haven't tested this.